# No route matches [GET] "/links/1/like" - Ruby On Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello im doing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-1HCWbu7iU and im up to 50.07min. Im new to ruby. Been studying for 3 weeks.

I just loaded Acts As Votable Gem. Loaded it as per instructions. I was able to add an upvote using ruby console. So it seems to work.

However.

**When i click upvote** I get this error **No route matches [GET] "/links/1/like"**

You can see an image of it at this link http://postimg.org/delete/8cmbm60j6/

**Below is my views>links>index.html.erb**

```
<% @links.each do |link| %>
  <div class="link row clearfix">
    <h2>
      <%= link_to link.title, link %><br>
      <small class="author">Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(link.created_at) %> by <%= link.user.email %></small>
    </h2>
<div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="<%= link.url %>">Visit Link</a>
      <%= link_to like_link_path(link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
        Upvote
        <%= link.get_upvotes.size %>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to dislike_link_path(link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">
        Downvote
        <%= link.get_downvotes.size %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Below is my routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :comments

  devise_for :users

  resources :links do
    member do
      put "like",    to: "links#upvote"
      put "dislike", to: "links#downvote"
    end
    resources :comments
  end
  root "links#index"
```

Anyone know what the problem is? Google isn't helping... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your route you have defined

```
put "like",    to: "links#upvote"
```

Which means that verb has to be 'PUT'

You are hitting 'GET' `/links/1/like`.
You nedd to change from `get` request to `put` request

You route is `[PUT] "/links/1/like"` not `[GET] "/links/1/like"`

Every link is `get` request, you need `ajax` request for this

Comment: You are a champion! Give yourself a high 5 before you go to bed tonight.

Comment: Just a quick one. When i Click "sign out" i get the same error

No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"

Where do i fix that error? I cant see anything that i should change to get instead of put....

Comment: Go to `config/initializers/devise.rb`. find `config.sign_out_via = :delete`, if no there put `config.sign_out_via = :get` or if exist change `:delete` to `:get`

Comment: It was there. So i changed to config.sign_out_via = :get

I still get the same error. Weird..

Comment: Restart rails server, because you have changed `initializers` file. also restart when you add gem

Answer (score 0):

Make your path in routes as get or post instead of put

For e.g.

`resources :links do
    member do
      get 'like'
      get 'dislike'
    end`

You are getting the error because you haven't specified the routes in your routes file.

Comment: What if someone by accident opens `/links/1/like` then he will get upvote, this is not god practice.

Comment: GET should only be used for non-changing requests. i.e. if you requested it a 1000 times, nothing would change. Generally crawlers will follow GET links and you may end up with lots of fake up/down votes

Answer (score 0):

@joeyk16, just try to change `:method => :put` option to `:data => {:method => :put}` and include jquery_ujs in your application.js (if you haven't yet).

So the link would looks like:

```
link_to dislike_link_path(link), :data => {:method => :put}, :class => "btn btn-default btn-sm"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solved it this way:

It turns out that the answer was related to JQuery. I was getting an Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined error and so what I did was include JQuery outright in my application.html.erb file.

You have to put this ahead of all your other scripts.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

After that, the voting began to work

Answer (score 0):

For my routes, I removed the `member do` bit:

```
resources :links do
    #member do
      put "Like",    to: "links#upvote"
      put "Dislike", to: "links#downvote"
    #end
end
```

After running rake routes I realised that the path name has been changed as well. Here's my **app/views/links/index.html.erb**:

```
<% @links.each do |link| %>
 <div class="link row clearfix">
    <h2>
        <%= link_to link.title, link %><br />
        <small class="author">Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(link.created_at) %> by <%= link.user.email %></small>
    </h2>

    <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="<%= link.url %>">Visit Link</a>
        <%= link_to link_Like_path(link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
          Upvote
          <%= link.get_upvotes.size %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to link_Dislike_path(link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">
            Downvote
            <%= link.get_downvotes.size %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

apparently it's now `link_Like_path(link)` & `link_Dislike_path(link)`

Hope this helps